# Как сохранять None вместо пустой строки из ModelForm?

Tags: python, django

Как в Django при использовании ModelForm сохранять в базе для пустых полей не пустую строку, а None?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Model
class Model1:
    field1 = forms.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

...
# Form
    def cleaned_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cd = super().cleaned_data(*args, **kwargs)
        if not cd['field1']:
            cd['field1'] = None

    return cd
```

Comment: Ну то есть вы таки предлагаете руками проверять поля на пустоту и если поле пустое - подставлять None? Странно, мне представлялось, что это должно происходить как-то само :)

Comment: в таком случае наверное, надо переопределять метдод clean, а не cleaned_data

Comment: Для строковых полей, нужно самому ставить значение None, так как формы получают из POST не `None`, а `''`

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Model1:
    field1 = forms.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
```

`blank = False` должен помочь